# Receiving HEAD requests continuously in asp net core middleware

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I am using asp net core 3.0 for my WEB API project. I have created a middleware. In middleware, I am facing a strange issue. When I kept a debugger point on InvokeAsync(), I noticed that InvokeAsync() gets called automatically and continuously. On further debugging, I found out that the HEAD request gets called automatically and it is calling the InvokeAsync() function. Suppose, the URL for my project is http://localhost:5000/, then I am receiving continuous requests for http://localhost:5000/ with HEAD method.

Middleware

```
public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            await HandleErrorAsync(context, exception);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleErrorAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        var response = new { message = exception.Message };
        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(payload);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs (Only mentioning the Configure())

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());



        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();



        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();



        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        //Configuring serilog
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

    }
```

Comment: How do you call the api from your client?It is possible that your js code send the HEAD request continuously.Do you have problem if you test with postman?

Comment: No. right now I am only using swagger and postman to test APIs. Till now there is not any client application.